# Time delay using IIR filters

Tags: signal-processing, dsp, digital-filter

I am trying to implement a cardioid pattern with two microphones.

I was reading this paper titled "Digital Filter Array Optimization for Directivity Pattern". The link to download the paper is [this](https://csce.ucmss.com/cr/books/2017/LFS/CSREA2017/HIM3033.pdf).

The premise of the paper is

"*Two microphone arrays are used for producing a specific  directivity pattern by a time delay between the two microphones. Directional hearing aids are examples of the two microphone arrays application. In this paper, the conventional time delay method was replaced with a digital filter method for directional digital hearing aids.*"

On the second page of the paper, it states,

"*If DF1 and DF2  are  optimally  designed  so  as  to  produce  the  same  magnitude   response,   but   the   constant   phase   difference   response  between  DF1  and  DF2,  the  resulting  y[n]  in  figure  2 should be the same as x[n] in figure 1.* "

I'm guessing the above statement should instead read "so  as  to  produce  the  same  magnitude   response,   but   **varying**   phase   difference   response"

My guess is by keeping the magnitude the same between the two signals, but varying phase should be equivalent of causing a time delay between the two signals. Am i right?

If so, how can I calculate filter co-efficients to vary the phase between the two signals in order to produce an exact time delay of few micro seconds?

Comment: Sounds like the paper author was being lazy, and wrote phase when they meant time delay. I think it would be far more likely to be expressed as constant time delay, rather than linear phase difference (which means the same thing).

Comment: A steer, as you've had no further replies. Getting differential time delay with FIR filters is dead easy, more problematic with IIR. Bessel filters give you flat delay, but a droopy passband, which may not be what you want. Cheby filters can give you reasonably flat delay to about 50% of the passband edge, which if you have bandwidth to burn can make for a reasonable design. Once you have a prototype with classical analogue filters, implement in IIR.

Comment: @Neil_UK you mentioned that it is more problematic with IIR filters. What kind of problems arise with IIRs? Is it the frequency shift ?

Comment: It's not so much that IIRs are more difficult, they are no more difficult to design than analogue time shifting filters, the simplest method of design is through pole zero placement, it's just that FIRs are much easier as you have explicit access to the impulse response.

Comment: Let's see if I can give you a start. What's the bandwidth of the signal you want to delay? What's the sampling rate? Do you have some reason for wanting IIR over FIR? What are your DSP/computing resources (word length, fixed or floating point, multiplies per second)? What fidelity of delay do you need (accurayc in time, flatness in amplitude, freedom from aliasing artifacts)? Then we can think about design.

Comment: The bandwidth of the signal is 8000 Hz. Sampling rate = 16000 Hz. I am trying to implement this on a CSR chip. My reason from choosing IIR is the fewer filter taps. Word length is 24 bit fixed point. A multiplication takes 3 clock cycles. A cardioid pattern requires 26.17 micro seconds applied to the second microphone. As for the flatness, i would prefer the signal remains unaltered as much as possible across the entire bandwidth.

Comment: Signal bandwidth = 0.5 * sampling bandwidth is impossible to do, Nyquist could use infinite length filters. Think again what your real required bandwidth is. Hint, anything above 0.25 * fs gets to be very expensive in filter taps, whichever way it's done.

Comment: @Neil_UK Ahh. 500 Hz. Just to help me better understand, let me ask a question. So if this filter will only delay a bandwidth of 500 Hz, then will I have to add multiple filters to delay each frequency component (across the entire spectrum) that I wish to delay ?

Comment: No, you delay the entire wanted passband in one filter. However, as the width of the passband increases, you need more and more computations, whether FIR or IIR, to keep the passband flat (to within your specification) for both time and amplitude. With FIR filters, the number of taps is (roughly) inversely proportional to the width of the transition band to keep amplitude flatness, but time delay is always perfect. With IIR, it gets harder to design via the bilinear transform, and it becomes non-flat in both amplitude and delay. DC-500Hz at 16kHz for sub-sample delay, sounds fairly OK.

Comment: I have to go offline for a few hours. However, a first order low pass filter ought to get you there. A pole at 6120Hz has a delay of 26uS, and will be pretty damned flat out to 500Hz. All you need to do is convert that pole location into a value of k for this first order y_t+1 = y_t (1-k) + k.x_t lowpass IIR filter stage. Above 500Hz, both the delay and amplitude drop off. 6120Hz is such a large fraction of 16kHz that you will probably need to do frequency warping / bilinear transform to get the right value of k. I'll compare that to an FIR design later today.

Comment: @Neil_UK Could you please let me know the math using which you arrived at "A pole at 6120Hz has a delay of 26uS, and will be pretty damned flat out to 500Hz." . No worries about being offline. You can reply when you get back. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: 6120Hz = 38450 rad/s = 1/26.17uS, which is the delay you want to achieve. This is the delay of a first order filter. As 500Hz << 6kHz, the filter will not have rolled off much into the -3dB at 6kHz. An FIR filter would consist of the following, y_t+1 = 0.58x_t + 0.42x_t-1. Same number of multiplies as the FIR, unconditionally stable, absolutely correct delay, less than 0.1dB down at 500Hz. If you want flatter amplitude, then a third coefficient can be added. 0.42 = 26.17uS / 62.5uS (works only for passband << fs and two coefficients), need to dust off MATLAB to do more than 2 coefficients

Comment: @Neil_UK that was very helpful. I'm going to have read a lot more to get proficient like you are. Could you point me in the direction of some documents/books that you refer to when you want help designing filters? Or the books that helped you when you got started . Thank you.

Comment: Reading is good, but doing is 100x better. I've had 40 years of doing this stuff. Start with understand poles and zeroes for analogue filters, they map over (almost) directly onto IIR filters. Understand time/frequency FFT pairs, they map directly onto FIR filters. Use a good environment, MATLAB if you've access to it, python + numpy + scipy + matplotlib is better, not as integrated, but free. And play. Implement very low order filters (like these) and see what they do. I'll see if I can identify some suitable books, a lot has changed since I studied.

Comment: `Ahh. 500 Hz. Just to help me better understand, let me ask a question. So if this filter will only delay a bandwidth of 500 Hz, then will I have to add multiple filters to delay each frequency component (across the entire spectrum) that I wish to delay ?` I didn't quite answer this question properly. The filter changes the response in the entire Nyquist bandwidth, but it's only in the passband that the change is within specification of what you want, outside the passband it's wrong. The smaller the passband, the bigger the don't care region, the lower order filter you need.

Comment: @Neil_UK "_but it's only in the passband that the change is within specification of what you want, outside the passband it's wrong_ " I realised that. so i'm trying to see how much the filter order i have to increase to increase the passband.   i've been reading and found that FIR filters have no poles and contain only zeros. But you've manged to derive coefficients ( y_t+1 = 0.58x_t + 0.42x_t-1) using a pole for a FIR filter. How did you manage to do that ?

Comment: No, I didn't use a pole for the FIR. I used linear interpolation to derive the time delay.   A 0.5 + 0.5 filter would delay by 31.25uS. It's possible to use this low order because 16kHz is so oversampled wrt 500Hz, so a 2 tap filter is reasonably amplitude flat near DC. This filter is zero at fs/2, and 0.58+0.42 nearly zero there, so you see the frequency response dropping off across the whole nyquist band. What frequency response visualisation tools do you have to hand? I looked for online tools recently, but a quick search drew a blank.

Comment: @Neil_UK i have MATLAB.

Comment: I accidently told an untruth back there, though you wouldn't discover it until you got a long way into playing with the filters and seeing what they did. The 0.58+0.42 FIR filter does not have perfect time delay, does not have linear phase, as it's assymetric. It's good enough however over your passband. Symmetric FIRs have perfect linear phase. Learn to use MATLAB to plot frequency responses of filter impulse responses. There ought to be plenty of examples out there to follow. Just beware the 1-based array indexing, a right PITA when assigning frequencies to FFT bins!

Comment: @Neil_UK Thanks a ton Neil. all these are very helpful to get me started. I wish i could upvote you :) .

Comment: As you have MATLAB, what I would recommend is plotting the frequency, phase and time delay response of the first order IIR filter mentioned above for various values of k, and the two tap ((1-a), a) FIR filter for various values of a, and see how the amplitude and delay changes over DC-500Hz, and outside that frequency. Understanding comes through experiment.

Comment: The easiest way to conceptualise how the filter causes delay, and so how to tailor the impulse to the desired delay, is to consider the 'centre of gravity' of the impulse response, whether IIR or FIR. This is the position of an effective single tap at DC. As we move away from DC, the detail of the impulse response will change the delay slightly, but 500Hz is pretty much DC compared to 16kHz, so very low order filters suffice.

Comment: @Neil_UK Sorry. i just saw your reply. Thank you for that. Yes, i have been implementing filters in MATLAB and practicing. I do have a question. I was reading this paper , (http://eeweb.poly.edu/iselesni/EL713/zoom/linphase.pdf). On page 5, he mentions that When ω1= 0.31π, then the delay is−θ(ω1)/ω1= 2.45. How did he arrive at that? For a linear phase filter, the phase delay can be equated to half a sample. But i can't figure out how 2.45 came about.